# Convert date from readable string to more standard

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have dates in the form `Fri 27th Aug`, which is a nightmare programmatically as I'm sure you can imagine.

I am wondering how best to convert these to the US date form `08/27/13`. I need to specify the year from the month, i.e. Aug-Dec imply `13`, and Jan-Jul imply `14`.

I was thinking about looking up how to do this in regex, or even just do a series of string replacements.

But the complication is that I have a list of strings, not all of which are dates of this form. If others have numbers inside, how can I test for a date of this form, and then replace if it is?

e.g.

`list = ['not a date', 'als0 not a dat3', 'Wed 5th Jan', ... , 'no date here']`

The requirement to test makes regex seem suitable, but I've read a lot on SO against the use of `re` in Python, though I don't know why. Should I (learn enough to use, and) use it?

**With @Allan's answer, I have been able to solve my issue with:**

```
def is_date(string):
    tmp = string.replace('th','')
    string = tmp.replace('rd','')
    tmp = string.replace('nd','')
    string = tmp.replace('st','')
    try:
        d = strptime(string, "%a %d %b")
        date = str(d[1]) + "/" + str(d[2]) + "/"
        if d[1] >= 8:
            date += "13"
        else:
            date += "14"
        return date
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Thanks for your answers, @Allan, @adsmith, and @codnodder.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [time.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime). It raises `ValueError`, so you might want to catch that exception and ignore for strings that are not dates.

I would avoid using regular expressions in this case, since date formatting can get pretty complex. You would need to specify the possible month and weekday abbreviations, check for case variation... You really, really don't want to go there if all you need is to solve a simple and well defined problem :)

@OllieFord: Improving on your new code, I arrived at:

```
import datetime

def is_date(string):
    for suffix in ("th", "rd", "nd", "st"):
        string = string.replace(suffix, "")

    try:
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%a %d %b")
        y = 2014
        if d.month >= 8:
            y = 2013            
        d = d.replace(year = y)
        return d.strftime("%x")
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

It uses functions from the datetime class to avoid manual work. Note the use of `%x` in the conversion to a string: it will use your current locale to format the date. This might be what you want, or maybe not...

I'd also take a look at `Dateutil.parser` which @Marian mentioned. If you don't care about adding an external dependency, it seems to solve this problem too, perhaps even more easily (I haven't tried it though).

Comment: `strptime` is going to have a rather hard time with ordinals like `27th`.

Comment: That's true... perhaps pre-processing the list could help... If it isn't possible, I would use three variations of the format string: "%a %b %dth", "%a %b %dnd", "%a %b %dst". Of course, that assumes this is the only format in which dates are expressed in list. If there are more, than things will get really hard anyway :D

Comment: The "date formats [sic]" cannot "get pretty complex", since there is a single, known format.

Comment: I'm with @Allan on this one. Using regex is overly complicated for what seems to be a fairly straight forward script. I'd do exactly as he proposes and try strptime, if it throws a `ValueError` then try the next ordinal, if it throws a ValueError then try the NEXT ordinal, then pass on that except.

Comment: @OllieFord if there's only one format, then preprocess from that format and run it through strptime. I can edit Allan's answer to give a good way to do that, if he doesn't want to do so himself.

Comment: @adsmith updating OP with what I have, appreciate help.

Comment: @OllieFord Hmm although I'm sure the implementation I was thinking of could still be used, I didn't catch that you needed to differentiate years. That may be another layer of obfuscation that could make a regex an easier solution. I'm still working on it....

Comment: @OllieFord I've edited Allan's answer with some example code as I feel like he had essentially the correct solution. If he doesn't accept the edit soonish I'll add my own answer, but I believe my code now is complete and manages to avoid the expensive regex overhead.

Comment: @adsmith I think I don't have enough reputation to review the edit :( And other people rejected it... I tried to give a more complete answer, but feel free to add your own.

Comment: @Allan your code works just as well as mine did, and in fact I think your implementation is cleaner and easier to use. The only thing mine did differently was `dayname, day, month = string.split()` in order to do `if month in ("Jan","Feb"...): year=2014 else: year=2013`, then `datetime.strptime("{} {} {} {}".format(dayname,day[:-2],month,year),"%a %d %b %Y")`

Answer (score 2):

Dateutil.parser will do this and more for you:

http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c

Answer (score 2):

A regex does not seem like the worst idea for this specific task. Below is a long example. I am sure there are numerous more efficient approaches.

```
import re

# Convert dates like "Fri 27th Aug" with year fudge
mons = {
    'Aug' : ( 8, 13),
    'Sep' : ( 9, 13),
    'Oct' : (10, 13),
    'Nov' : (11, 13),
    'Dec' : (12, 13),
    'Jan' : ( 1, 14),
    'Feb' : ( 2, 14),
    'Mar' : ( 3, 14),
    'Apr' : ( 4, 14),
    'May' : ( 5, 14),
    'Jun' : ( 6, 14),
    'Jul' : ( 7, 14),
}
days = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')

# pattern is purposefully strict to avoid false matches against
# other arbitrary strings
pat = re.compile(r'^(%s) (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) (%s)$' %
                 ('|'.join(days), '|'.join(mons.keys())))
strlist = ['not a date', 'als0 not a dat3', 'Wed 5th Jan', 'no date here']
newlist = []
for tok in strlist:
    m = re.match(pat, tok)
    if m:
        day = int(m.group(2))
        mon = m.group(4)
        newlist.append('%02d/%02d/%02d' % (mons[mon][0], day,mons[mon][1]))
    else:
        newlist.append(tok)

for tok in newlist:
    print tok
```

EDIT: Changed date format to match OP correction.

Comment: Woops, sorry. Actually the former "Wed 5th Jan" style was correct. I have edited your answer accordingly - but I'm not totally familiar with regex so please correct if wrong. Will accept once confirmed.

Comment: I like this solution though - the `mons` dict is a far neater method for getting month and year than I would have hacked together.

Comment: I'm trying to apply `re` to another couple of functions. Why doesn't `\d+[:]\d+` match times of form `21:20`?

Comment: It probably does, although the square brackets around the colon are unnecessary, and you do not have the `\d+` match in parenthesis so they will not be captured. Also, look up the difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()` as it makes a difference depending on what you are searching. Perhaps submit another question with the details of this new problem? Best.